# What is adb in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I get the following errors when I try to run my Android program.

Please explain me What really `adb` is, and how to restart it?

I am getting the following error

```
The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
You must restart adb and Eclipse.
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

adb is [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html).

To restart adb by command line:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

To restart adb in Eclipse:

1. Window > Show View > Other... > Android/Devices
2. When the view is showing: View Menu of "Devices" > Reset adb

Comment: When I do "Reset adb", I get this error messages: [2012-04-19 12:53:35 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2012-04-19 12:53:36 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1

Comment: @DUKE It seems that the Android virtual device has an active connection with adb, that's why those warning message appears. I suggest to close Eclipse and use the command line method to restart adb, and then restart Eclipse to see how it works?

Answer (score 2):

ADB stands for **Android Debug Bridge**.

Android Debug Bridge (adb) is a versatile command line tool that lets you communicate with an emulator instance or connected Android-powered device.

[image]

This info and more can be found [here](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/12/android-debug-bridge-adb.html), on my blog.

As for restarting adb server you can execute following commands

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

As for Eclipse simply close the IDE and restart/reopen. Infact restarting Eclipse should restart adb server as well.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this problem on Eclipse, and it reported that I needed to 'reset adb from the Device's view'. The adb kill&restart-server sequence didn't work for me, **but I was successful with just disabling and then re-enabling the 'USB debugging' check box in the phone's Settings->Developer Options**

Comment: Sorry, I had initially thought this was a question, but it actually is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

i also came across with this problem, i got this error **please ensure that adb is correctly located “Users/semihozkoroglu/ADT/sdk/platform-tools/adb” and can be executed**

Click devices dropdown - > reset adb, its works..

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score -2):

ADB is a Android Debug Bridge.

Following for more Details ADB

http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/what-is-adb-and-how-to-install-it-android/

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

Close And Open Eclipse,Adb is automatically restarted..!

Thanks..!